# Evitar ID's repetidos

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy generando botones dinamicamente pero al momento de hacer clic sobre un botón, y hacer clic sobre otro y nuevamente al primero que le di clic (Espero haberme explicado) me arroja un error y me dice que se han encontrado multiples controles con el mismo ID

> Multiple controls with the same ID were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

Este es mi codigo y como intento evitar que los id's se repitan:

```
protected void DynamicButton()
    {

        //BAD TOOLS INTO THE LIST AND SHOW
        List.ListUsers listsArea = new List.ListUsers();
        List<Data.Area> Area = listsArea.AreaList();

        List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposNoOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == "ENG" && x.STANDBY == 1).ToList();

        List<Button> BotonesBad = new List<Button>();

        var TeamBad = ListOfEquiposNoOk.Select(x => x.TEAM).Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (var team in TeamBad)
        {
            Button newButtonBad = new Button();
            if (newButtonBad.ID != newButtonBad.ID)
            {
                BotonesBad = Bad.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
                BotonesBad.Add(newButtonBad);
            }
            else
            {
                newButtonBad.CommandName = "Btn" + Convert.ToString(team);
                newButtonBad.ID = "BtnB_" + Convert.ToString(team);
                newButtonBad.Text = team;
                newButtonBad.CommandArgument = "ENG";
                newButtonBad.Click += new EventHandler(newButton_Click);

                Bad.Controls.Add(newButtonBad);
                newButtonBad.Click += new EventHandler(newButton_Click);

                newButtonBad.CssClass = "btn-primary outline separate";
            }
        }
```

**AGREGADO**

```
public partial class Dashboard : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static bool enableGood = false;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DynamicButton();
            }
            else if(enableGood)
            {
                DynamicButton();
            }
        }

        protected void DButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showAndHide();", true);

            enableGood = true;
            DynamicButton();
        }
```

Esta parte del codigo es con la que `DynamicButton` se ejecute, si le quito

```
else if(enableGood)
            {
                DynamicButton();
            }
```

el error se arregla, pero si lo hago de esa manera, el evento jamas se ejecuta

Comment: Y para necesitas el ID?

Comment: lo necesito para poder ejecutar un `UpdatePanel`

Comment: Te recomiendo que pongas un punto de interrupción en el foreach para poder seguir paso a paso (cómo se están generando los ids. Además, en tu código hay cosas muy raras, por ejemplo: if (newButtonBad.ID != newButtonBad.ID) ¿En qué situación un objeto sería distinto de sí mismo?

Comment: Ya he generado puntos de interrupcion y al momento en que vuelvo a dar clic sobre un boton al que ya se le dio clic anteriormente, en efecto corre el ciclo, pero al momento en que termina, se vuelve a ejecutar, no se por que, y es por eso que se repiten los id's. y pues en mi idea era esa, en que si son iguales, no hiciera nada y solo agregara el objeto a la lista

Comment: El ciclo se puede estar ejecutando doble porque estás agregando dos veces el handler del click: newButtonBad.Click += new EventHandler(newButton_Click);

Comment: Y si quieres recuperar el id de un control de la pagina lo tendrias que hacer con el método FindControl del Form. Es obvio que si estás instanciando un objeto y a continuación preguntas si una propiedad de ese objeto es distinta a la misma propiedad del mismo objeto, ese if siempre va a ser false.

Comment: le he quitado esa parte que se repetia pero no ha sido ese el problema

Comment: Me queda la duda, pero éste if está correcto?: if (newButtonBad.ID != newButtonBad.ID)